# Hook kernel exception handler with Windows driver

Tags: c++, c, windows, driver, fault

I am looking to hook the exception handling process when a nonexecutable memory page is executed or a nonreadable memory page is read. I am unsure if this is possible without subverting PatchGuard. What kind of driver object do I need to create if this is possible?